# Gmock for static methods

Tags: testing, controller, agent

I am using Gmock for testing.I got a class where all the methods are static. 
For Example

```
class A
{
  static int Method1(int x,int y){return (x+y)};
};
```

How do I test this class using Gmock.
Please help me out.
Thanks

Comment: I guess you're asking how to mock the methods right? Not test the class, since that would be trivial in your example

Comment: Something like this.

class B
{
void xyz{ A::Method1(x,y)}
}

this is the case.How Do I Gtest Class B.
I know I have to mock Class A.But without making any changes in the source code.How Can I test B?

Comment: Without modifications, you cannot mock Method1 when testing class B. Given your example it's a bit hard to give concrete advice as the call to Method1 is pointless. If you just want to verify that the call was done correctly, perhaps inject the static method in B's constructor and pass a mock function when testing.

Comment: Thank you .But I can't change the code.Can Stub be used?If so How?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it without modification of your code. But you can link your application with stubbed object. Just create another "class A" implementation and link it with your test application.

Answer (score 0):

- sorry for my previous answer not sufficient to explain your question. *

gmock is not supporting mocking a static function and non-virtual function so far. It works when you have a virtual method in legacy code, and when you are able to put a new mock class as a subclass into it.
I'm suggesting a new solution by using "[jomock](https://github.com/jonah512/jomock)" which supports mocking legacy global function, static method, and non-virtual method without changing legacy code.

```
// for your example.. 
class A
{
  static int Method1(int x,int y){return (x+y)};
};

#include "jomock.h"
TEST(JoMock, testStaticFunction) 
{
    EXPECT_CALL(JOMOCK(A::Method1), JOMOCK_FUNC(_,_))
        .Times(Exactly(1))
        .WillOnce(Return(1));

    EXPECT_EQ(A.Method1(1,2), 1);    
}
// this is a little modification from the jomock example.
// https://github.com/jonah512/jomock
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do that by creating Independent Mock Class which will not be derived from the class which you need to Mock. Here is how you will do that.

Step - 1 : Comment the class having static function

```
// Comment the class
/*
    class A 
    {
      static int Method1(int x,int y){return (x+y)};
    };
*/
```

Step - 2: Created a Mock class with the same name as `A` and mock the `Method1` in it. Please note that its not derived from original class

```
class A  {
public:
    MOCK_METHOD2(Method1, int(int x, int y));
};
```

Let's assume that the class which is using the static function which needs to be mocked it `UsingA`. Here is how it could be written.

```
class UsingA {
    A  &a1;
public:
    UsingA(A & _a1) : a1(_a1) {} 
    int CallFn() {
        // Original function that needs to be commented
        // return a1::Method1(10,25);
        return a1.Method1(10, 20);
    }
};
```

Then here is how you'll write the test

```
TEST(MyMockTest, Method1Test) {
    A mstat;
    UsingA ua(mstat);

    EXPECT_CALL(mstat, Method1(_,_))
    .Times(1)
    .WillOnce(Return(100));

    int retVal = ua.CallFn();

    EXPECT_EQ(retVal,100); 

}
```

May not be the best way but servers the purposed. Hope it helps