# Factory Pattern w/ Gmock

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I have a interface where I am using the factory pattern to create an instance of the object and store it in a unique_ptr. I also have a MockInterface which I would like to use in my tests to not call the actual production code. However when I run my tests the production interface is called instead of the mock. What am I doing wrong??

***Interface.hpp***

```cpp
class Interface
{
      Interface() {};
      virtual ~Interface() = default;
      virtual int foo() = 0;
      virtual int bar() = 0;
      static std::unique_ptr<Interface> create();
};
```

***Interface.cpp***

```cpp
#include "Interface.hpp"
#include "Impl.hpp"

std::unique_ptr<Interface> Interface::create()
{
    return std::unique_ptr<Interface> { new Impl() };
}
```

***Impl.hpp***

```cpp
class Impl : public Interface
{
    Impl() {};
    ~Impl() {};
    virtual int foo();
    virtual int bar();
};
```

***Impl.cpp***

```cpp
#include "Interface.hpp"
#include "Impl.hpp"

int Impl::foo()
{
    return 2;
}

int Impl::bar()
{
    return 2;
}
```

```cpp
class MockInterface : public Interface
{
   MockInterface() {};
   ~MockInterface() {};
   MOCK_METHOD(int, foo, (), (override));
   MOCK_METHOD(int, bar, (), (override));
}
```

***lib.cpp***

```cpp
#include "Interface.hpp"

class Foo
{
    public:
        Foo() { inst = Interface::create(); }
        virtual ~Foo() = default;
        void some_function();

    private:
        std::unique_ptr<Interface> inst; 
}
   
void Foo::some_function()
{
    int foo_ret = inst->foo();
    int bar_ret = inst->bar();
}
```

***test.cc***

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<Interface> Interface::create()
{    
    std::unique_ptr<MockInterface> mock { new MockInterface() };
    EXPECT_CALL(*mock, foo()).Times(1);
    EXPECT_CALL(*mock, bar()).Times(1);
    return mock;
}

TEST_F(fixture, test_foo)
{
    // This will pass but I will get an error "mock object never deleted"
    // Will also leave my terminal in a bad state
    Foo *obj = new Foo(); 
    obj->some_function();

   // This will fail also leaving my terminal in a bad state
   Foo obj2;
   obj2.some_function();
}
```

Comment: the first piece of code should compile?

Comment: You have several syntax errors. `class Interface:`, `virtual int foo = 0;`, and so on. Please provide a [mcve]. What method is supposed to call `foo`?

Comment: `virtual int foo = 0;` - what is this supposed to do?

Comment: Added more details.

Answer (score 0):

`some_function()` calls `Interface::create()`, which has not been mocked, so it's still going to give you back a unique pointer pointing to an `Impl` object, not a `MockInterface` object.

To solve this you can either mock out `Interface::create` to have it return your mocked object, or have `some_function` receive a pointer/reference to `Interface` as a parameter instead of calling `Interface::create` itself. Then just pass it your mocked object.

The simplest way to mock the create function is to just redefine it for your tests. Exclude `Interface.cpp` from your test program since the function can only be defined once

```
std::unique_ptr<Interface> Interface::create()
{
    std::unique_ptr<MockInterface> mock { new MockInterface() };
    EXPECT_CALL(*mock, foo()).Times(1);
    return mock;
}

TEST_F(fixture, test_foo)
{
    some_function();
}
```

To provide different implementations for each test you can do something like this:

```
std::function<std::unique_ptr<Interface>()> creator;

std::unique_ptr<Interface> Interface::create()
{
    return creator();
}

TEST_F(fixture, test_foo)
{
    creator = []() {
        std::unique_ptr<MockInterface> mock { new MockInterface() };
        EXPECT_CALL(*mock, foo()).Times(1);
        return mock;
    };
    // Will call Interface::create which will call creator()
    some_function();
}
```

Comment: But Interface::create is a static function. How would I go about mocking that?

Comment: @developer_in_the_making There are a couple options. See for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45697358/5522303) and [here](https://github.com/google/gwtmockito/issues/59). Basically, either stub it out by compiling your test with a different implementation of `Interface::create`, or replace it with a non-static function and pass objects around that you *can* mock.

Comment: How about using templates ? Where in production code create() returns actual implementation and in tests it returns the mock? I have not used a template before just read about it so I am looking for a good example .

Comment: Templates won't solve anything here. But you can just link in a different implementation for `Interface::create` instead of compiling/linking `Interface.cpp` into your test program. Just remove `Interface.cpp` from your test makefile (assuming you have one) and define `std::unique_ptr<Interface> Interface::create() { return std::make_unique<MockInterface>(); }` in your test program.

Comment: Yes. I do have a makefile. I like that. I will create a test implementation of Interface.cpp which just returns the mock interface.

Comment: I removed Interface.cpp from my Makefile and implemented Interface::create() in my test program. However I am getting a seg fault when running it. Is this because gmock and the some_function() both have a reference to a unique_ptr ?

Comment: A unique_ptr is the sole owner of an object, so yes, you can only have 1 unique_ptr pointing to an object. But if you need to you can grab a reference to the object before you pass ownership to the caller of `Interface::create` (e.g. `MockInterface &ref = *ptr;`).

Comment: Can you reply based my example above? What would I do in test.cc. Knowing that some_function() is going to create the unique_ptr.

Comment: @developer_in_the_making I updated my answer

Comment: The scenario I am working with is slightly different. I updated my question to reflect this. When I instantiate the class Foo the constructor calls Interface::create() and saves the unique_ptr as a private member. When I run the gtest I see the message for an interesting call but I am not able to figure out how to setup my expectations

Comment: @developer_in_the_making The mock expectations are checked when the mock object is destroyed. Since it's being held by the `Foo` object and you never delete the `Foo` object, it won't be deleted. Just get rid of `new` and use a `Foo` object directly (you should basically *never* use `new` in C++ these days): `Foo foo; foo.some_function();`. It will be destroyed at the end of the test function which will destroy the mock, which will check the expectations you set up.

Comment: I put my expectations in the create() function to check for foo and bar. If I use new the test passes but I get the error: "Error: this mock object used ........ should be deleted but never is. If I dont use new and simply do Foo obj; obj.some_function() I dont get the error above but my test fails saying that the expectations are not met.

Comment: @developer_in_the_making Add a virtual destructor to `Interface`: `virtual ~Interface() = default;`. That's required for polymorphic types that you delete through the base class, which happens in this case.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mcve] of the problem

Comment: Updated example.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the problem. Does your fixture do anything special?

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks. I am using an adapter to call legacy C functions. And in one of my methods I was using the C function directly and not the adapter. Hence when I mock that legacy C function was making an actual hardware call. Appreciate all the help.